# Maximal number of edges in $C_4$-free graph

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, proof-explanation, extremal-graph-theory

I was reading the book "Extremal combinatorics" by S.Jukna but I came across a moment which seems confusing to me (probably wrong).

[image]

**Question:** For $v\in V$ the degree $d_G(v)$ is defined as the number of edges incident with $v$, i.e. $d_G(v):=\#\{e\in E: e \ \text{incident with} \ v\}$. In general $d_G(v)$ may not be equal to $|N(v)|$, where $N(v)$ - the set of neighbors of $v$.

The authors says "we have $\binom{d_u}{2}$ possibilities to choose a $2$-element subset of its $d_u$ neighbors." I think that it is not correct. What if $d_u=0,1$? What $d_u=2$ and some edge $e$ is a loop around $u$?

Can anyone explain how to fix that?

Comment: Don't post unsearchable images of text.  Instead, use *MathJax*.  The search tools cannot find it.  It may be, for instance, that this precise problem has already been asked and answered.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The equation

$$\binom{d_u}2= \text{ # ways to select two distinct neighbors of $u$}\tag{$\star$}$$

is correct as long as $G$ is a simple graph, meaning no loops and no multiple edges. The author is implicitly assuming the $G$ is simple, so their argument is fine.

How do I know the author is assuming no loops and multiple edges?

- The author must be excluding multiple edges, since the result is blatantly false when you allow them. Just consider the graph with $n=2$ vertices and two parallel edges connecting the two vertices. You can see $2=|E|\le \frac{2}4(1+\sqrt{4\cdot 2-3})\approx 1.618$ is violated. In fact, you can add as many copies of an edge as you like, so you cannot prove *any* inequality of the from $|E|\le f(|V|)$ for graphs with multiple edges.
- The author must be excluding loops, because the result is false when you allow them. Again letting $n=2$, the graph $G=(V,E)=(\{1,2\},\{11,12,22\})$ has no four-cycles, yet $3=|E|\le \frac{2}4(1+\sqrt{4\cdot 2-3})\approx 1.618$ is violated.

I just noticed that you were concerned about what happens when $d_u\in \{0,1\}$. In these cases, $\star$ is still true, since both sides of $(\star)$ are zero. Note that $\binom nk$ is defined as the number of $k$-element subsets of an $n$-element set. Whenever $k>n$, there are $0$ such subsets, so $\binom nk=0$ when $k>n$.

Comment: One more question: when they consider the set $S$ consisting of all pairs $(u,\{v,w\})$ I guess we need to require that $u\neq v$ and $u\neq w$. Am I right?

Comment: They said "$S$ consists of all ordered pairs $(u,\{v,w\})$ such that $v\neq w$ and $u$ is adjacent to $v$ and $w$." Since $G$ is simple, $u$ being adjacent to $v$ implies $u\neq v$, so there is no need to explicitly state $u\neq v$. $\tag*{}$ Granted, it would be better to state in the conditions of the theorem that $G$ is simple. This omission is only forgivable if at some point earlier in the text, the author said that all graphs should be assumed to be simple unless otherwise stated. @PlayGame

Comment: Got it! If we consider graph $G$ with $V=\{1,2\}$ and $E=\{11,12\}$, then $d_G(1)=1+2=3$ and $N_G(1)=\{1,2\}$. Right? Just want to be sure that I understand definition of degree and neighbor correctly.

Comment: @PlayGame It is definitely true that $N_G(1)=\{1,2\}$. I am not sure how degree is defined when loops are around, but I think it is correct to say $d_G(1)=3$, i.e. that a loop is counted twice,.

Comment: Yeah loop is counted twice. In the first pages the defines degree as follows "The number $d(u)$ of neighbors of a vertex $u$ is its degree". Since this is true for simple graphs, then I guess in this book the author assumes that all graphs are simple.

Comment: Thank you so much for help! It was really good answer! +1