# Construction of dense $C_4$-free graph

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

Yesterday I created [the topic](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4399805/maximal-number-of-edges-in-c-4-free-graph) where we discussed the following theorem:

If $G=(V,E)$ is a simple and $C_4$-free graph, then $|E|\leq \dfrac{|V|}{4}(1+\sqrt{4|V|-3})$.

It is important to notice that this result is false if graph has loops and multiple edges.

In the following page of that book you can find the following: [image]

I would like to ask only two questions:

1. I would like to check that $G$ is undirected graph. As far as I know in the case of directed graphs edges are ordered pairs of vertices. How to check that $G$ is undirected graph?
2. In the theorem graph should be a simple. However, in this example some edges are loops. So it does not that the bound in Theorem 2.4 is optimal up to a constant. Am I right?

Answer (score 2):

1. The condition defining the edges of $G$ is symmetric with respect to the endpoints of the edge, so the graph is undirected.
2. There are at most $n$ loops, which is much less than the number of edges, so after removing the loops there are still $\Omega(n^{3/2})$ edges.

As a side note, the 'polarity graph' provides an optimal construction which gives equality for the initial theorem you posted, for infinitely many values of $n$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Let me ask you the following question: Fix some vertex $v$ in our graph $G$. Can we have more than loop around vertex $v$? I am a bit confused.

Comment: @PlayGame The way the graph is defined rules out the possibility of multiple edges, so multiple loops are not possible. They simply said that $(a,b)$ is joined to $(c,d)$ when $ac=b+d$. That is, either $(ab)$ and $(c,d)$ are joined, or they  are not joined, with no possibility for being joined multiple times.

Comment: @MikeEarnest, Thank you for your comment! Formally, our graph $G=(V,E)$ is defined as follows: $V=(\mathbb{Z}_p\setminus\{0\})\times \mathbb{Z}_p$ and $E=\{\{(a,b),(c,d)\}:(a,b)\in V, (c,d)\in V, ac=b+d\}$, right?

Comment: 1. Do we need to check that $E$ is symmetric under inclusion? I mean if $\{(a,b),(c,d)\}\in E$, then $\{(c,d),(a,b)\}\in E$? Why it is important to check that? I have started to learn graph theory recently and I am bit confused.

Comment: 2. In order to find $|E|$ we need to use the formula: $2|E|=\sum \limits_{v\in V}d_G(v)$. I am slightly confused that author says that graph $G$ is $(p-1)$-regular. Fix $(a,b)\in V$ and consider an equation $ax=b+y$. For each $x\neq 0$ we have unique $y$. It implies that $ax=b+y$ has exactly $p-1$ solutions for $(x,y)\in V$. But it does not imply that degree of $(a,b)$ is $p-1$, right? Because among the solutions could be $(a,b)$ and in this case the degree is $2+(p-2)=p$.

I would be really thankful if you can explain those questions. You can give a separate answer. I'll appreciate that!

Comment: @PlayGame, 1) a graph is a directed graph with a symmetric edge relation. 2) If you want to use that 'sum of degrees' formula, then you are right, some degrees are actually $p$, not $p-1$, so the author of this book is not entirely accurate. But the conclusion is still the same, since the number of edges is $n(p-1)/2$ if we only count the loops has 'half-edges,' and we delete the loops anyway.

Comment: @BobKrueger, what does "is a directed graph with a symmetric edge relation" mean? It sounds really confusing. I read the definition of graph from Murty-Bondy book and I do not remember these words. Could you be more specific?

Comment: @BobKrueger, 2) you cannot count loops as half edges. I am really confused :(

Comment: @MikeEarnest, can you answer my questions please?