# Graphs which do not contain $C_4$ as an induced subgraph

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, extremal-combinatorics, extremal-graph-theory

I know the definition of subgraph and induced subgraph but I am slightly confused with the following sentence

> Graphs that do not contain $C_4$ as an induced subgraph let them call *weakly $C_4$-free graphs*.

Let's take a look at the following picture: [image]

Graph $G$ contains several copies of $C_4$ as a subgraph, but none of them as an induced subgraph.

I am really confused how to check manually that $G$ does not contain $C_4$ as an induced subgraph.

Can anyone explain it with details, please?

Comment: Can you tell us what the definition of an induced subgraph is, and give a little more explanation about which part of applying that definition confuses you?

Comment: @MikeEarnest, If $G=(V,E)$ is a graph, then induced subgraph $H$ is obtained by deleting some vertices and all edges which are incident to deleted vertices.

In our case the graph $G=(V,E)$ is given as $V=\{1,2,3,4,5\}$ and $E=\{12,14,23,24,25,34,45\}$.

This graph contains 2 copies of $4$-cycle such as: $12341, 23452$.

The graph induced by vertices $\{1,2,3,4\}$ is $G[\{1,2,3,4\}]$ has edge set $\{12,14,23,24,34\}$.

The graph induced by vertcies $\{2,3,4,5\}$ is $G[\{2,3,4,5\}]$ has edge set $\{23,24,25,34,45\}$.

Comment: Hello :) @Mike Earnest. A graph $H$ is a subgraph of $G$, if $V(H) \subseteq V(G) $, $E(H) \subseteq E(G) $. $H$ is called induced subgraph, if additionally $\{u, v\}\in E(H) $ for all $u, v\in V(H) $ with $\{u, v\}\in E(G) $.

Comment: @Jochen, that question was intended to me

Comment: @MikeEarnest, Suppose $G=(V_G,E_G)$ is a graph. Subgraph $H$ is called an induced subgraph if $V_H\subseteq V_G$ and $E_H=\{\{u,v\}: u,v\in V_H, \{u,v\}\in E_G\}$.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a conceptually easy way to manually check if $G$ contains an induced $C_4$.

> Look at all ways to select four an ordered list of distinct vertices $v_1,v_2,v_3,v_4\in V(G)$. If for any of those selections, you have
> $$ v_1\sim v_2\text{ and }v_2\sim v_3\text{ and }v_3\sim v_4\text{ and }v_4\sim v_1\text{ and }v_1\not\sim v_3\text{ and }v_2\not\sim v_4 $$
> then you have found an induced $C_4$. If the above holds for none of the selections, then no induced $C_4$ exists.

The process for checking for a $C_4$ subgraph is the same, except you omit the requirements $v_1\not\sim v_3$ and $v_2\not\sim v_4$.

Comment: I still cannot get it. Why in my example the graph $G$ does not contain induced $C_4$ subgraph.

Comment: Because whenever you select four vertices in $G$ which are connected in a loop, they also have at least one "diagonal" edge present. Therefore, the graph induced by those four vertices is not isomorphic to $C_4$, since it contains that extra diagonal edge. That is all there is to it.

Comment: Why these 4 vertices should be taken in an ordered list?

Comment: @PlayGame You use ordered lists because you need to account for all the ways the four chosen vertices could be a cycle. If you look at vertices $a,b,c,d$, they could connect in a four-cycle like $a-b-c-d-a$, or like $a-c-d-b-a$, or like $a-c-b-d-a$, etc. You need to check all possibilities. If you still have questions, please [edit](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/4401104/edit) your question to narrow down your problem.

Comment: I'd be very grateful if you can explain my questions to your comment in this post https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4400415/construction-of-dense-c-4-free-graph

Comment: @PlayGame That comment chain is getting too long. If you still have concerns there, I think it would be best if you asked a new question.