# Optimizing a packing of $n$ cliques into $K_n$

Tags: combinatorics, contest-math, discrete-optimization

In a now-deleted question (previously [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4756665/find-max-m-for-counting)), user Lục Trường Phát posted what I thought was an interesting problem from a math competition at their school. To be clear, I don't know anything about this context, only that I found the question interesting. Let me rephrase it slightly:

> Over all packings of $n$ cliques into the complete graph $K_n$ (that is, using each edge in at most one clique), if the $k^\text{th}$ clique has $a_k$ vertices, what is the maximum value of $a_1+a_2+\cdots + a_n$?

After playing with this for a while and in particular finding some optimal packings for $n\leq 8$, I've conjectured that among the optimal packings is one such that all of the cliques have either $c$ or $c+1$ vertices, for $c=\left\lfloor\frac{1+\sqrt{4n-3}}{2}\right\rfloor$. This choice of $c$ is certainly the largest possible, by the natural edge-counting argument.

This would give fairly tight bounds on the maximum sum, including an exact answer when $\sqrt{4n-3}$ is an (odd) integer, but so far my attempts to prove it haven't succeeded.

Comment: In other words, what is the maximum number of edges in a $C_4$-free subgraph of $K_{n,n}$?

Comment: Ah! I think that's correct. The idea is that one partite set has the vertices of $K_n$ and the other partite set represents the cliques, and a $C_4$ would be a pair of vertices in two cliques, right?

Comment: With that in mind, [this seems relevant](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4399805/maximal-number-of-edges-in-c-4-free-graph). The missing edges in $K_{n,n}$ do seem to be costing us something like a $\sqrt{2}$ factor, but maybe the idea can be massaged.

Comment: This is the notorious [Zarankiewicz problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zarankiewicz_problem#Examples), OEIS sequence [A072567](https://oeis.org/A072567).

Comment: @user14111: Oh, very interesting, thank you! Although your comment may not address the $c,c+1$ conjecture, I think it would be appropriate as an Answer. (Although perhaps it does; if the constructions rely on the projective plane structure for $n=q^2+q+1$ then probably they fail at $q=6$?)

Comment: To tell the truth, I don't know anything about the Zarankiewicz problem, I just looked it up on the internet. (It's amazing how mny ombinatorics problems you can solve by plugging a few data points into the OEIS search box.) I'd rather see an Answer written by someone with actual knowledge.